# Convert a directory to VHD file?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I have a directory that contains **thousands** of files and folders, I need to copy it to a Ubuntu virtual machine in Hyper-V, so if I use copy or cloning to will take a lot of time, can I convert this directory to **VHD** file then attach it to that machine? Is there any way, I don't need to convert a partition, just that directory.

Any  ?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to directly convert a directory without copying, but a way to make an vhd file out of a directory would be to use `qemu-img`. First I'd make a new "raw" image with `qemu-img create`, format that raw image (e.g. `mkfs.ext4 <imagefile>`), loop-mount it, copy the files, unmount it and use `qemu-img convert` to convert it to VHD format (see `man qemu-img` for details). Nevertheless, this involves copying all files and converting the image - both things you probably want to avoid.

Comment: that's my problem , when i try to copy it takes two days :) my god , i hope there is a way directly .